# How to see difference or compare files using sublime?

Tags: files, sublime-text, editor, diff

Using sublime as notepad++ not available for ubuntu :(

I want to see differences among two files one is from repository and another is external file, is there any way to see difference using sublime, I can see that it provide a method in windows mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874018/comparing-the-contents-of-two-files-in-sublime-text

**but in ubuntu I cannot select multiple files using Ctrl.**

Thanks.

Comment: I have just tried this and it has worked. Using Sublime Text 3, build 3114

Comment: Yep, same here. SHIFT+CLICK works. I use it all the time actually.

Comment: Why can you not use ctrl?

Comment: In my above comment I meant to say that CTRL+CLICK **and** SHIFT+CLICK both work.

Comment: Try Installing the [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) plugin then try again.

Comment: Please add details as with SHIFT+CLICK or CTRL+CLICK switch the file but do not allow multi-select. I am using Build 3114 (same)

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs.

Comment: If this problem is with me only ?? because sublime has builtin compare file option